# Load PHP page in Cordova phonegap with using AJAX

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I want to show my php page in android mobile app. I use cordova and i added a php page in my project with this directory "php/load.php". I tried to show this page on index.html i tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="show();">Show it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function show(){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'php/load.php',
                dataType: 'text'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                })
        alert("Pause");
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is my php file:

```
<?php
$a = "AAAAAAAA";
echo $a ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got syntax errors in your JavaScript that's likely causing most of the problem. Have a look at this and give it a try.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#btn_show").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'php/load.php',
                dataType: 'text'
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
    <button type="submit" id="btn_show" >Show it</button>
```

Comment: Ok, can you post any errors you're seeing? Also, did you notice the addition of the `id="btn_show"` to the button itself?

Answer (score 0):

Four important points:

1. Listen to the cordova deviceready event
2. Your url in your ajax request is not local and it can't be local because on your device is no server running. So it has to be something like: https://www.example.com/load.php
3. You have to whitelisten all your external sources.
4. You should use https.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using json_encode function in php.
For example:

```
<?php
$a = "AAAAAAAA";
echo json_encode($a) ;
?>
```

this would return a json array object which you can use to be rendered by javascript then put on to those html element.

changing the url for ajax For example: "url:localhost/website/load.php" i think it must be done too for ajax to work properly.